# how does the new operator works on exceptions constructor without class declaration?

Tags: c#, .net

***how can you implement the constructor without naming or needing the class such
as
EX:

string x = new string()

how can i just implement

new string() by itself without the need for string x.

I known it's calling the constructor but doesn't the class has to be initialized?

Ex:

1. `new InvalidOperationException(".....")`
2. `throw new ArgumentException("...");`

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: What do you mean by `initialized`?  Somewhere internally in the .NET framework there are class definitions for `InvalidOperationException` and `ArgumentException`, and they have constructors with code that runs when the class is instantiated.  What's the problem/question?

Comment: @Fad Eyi: suggest you add more explanation, otherwise your question might be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example instantiates an `InvalidOperationException()`, but can't do anything with it because it's not saved to a variable or thrown. If you saved it to a variable, you could throw it later:

```
var excep = new InvalidOperationException();
throw excep;
```

Comment: My question is i have seen both examples in my initial question been used without instantiation. So how is that possible?

Comment: They are initialized by the code you posted. `new InvalidOperationException()` calls the constructor for `InvalidOperationException`, which is responsible for initialization.

Comment: But what variable are they stored in, the original code does have the "var excep" sessions it just goes straight into instantiation of the constructor. "new InvalidOperationException();". Maybe my question is not understood correctly. The code doesn't assign a variable to the constructor so how can it run?

Comment: The first code sample is worthless for just the reason you suggest; it's not being assigned to anything. I said so in my answer. But it is still creating and initializing the object - you just can't do anything with it. The second code is "throwing" the exception object; code up the stack somewhere will `catch` that exception and will get it there.

Comment: Thanks, i think that answered my question. So what you saying it's possible to create object without assigning variable it just means you can't do anything with it but how is throw one different  "The second code is "throwing" the exception object; code up the stack somewhere will catch that exception and will get it there" maybe i don't understand how "throw" works i though it would have the same effect as the first code.

Comment: I'd recommend looking up "Exception handling" in .NET for more on what `throw` does.

Comment: i Know what "throw" does in general i'm wondering how "catch" is incorporated?